# change the size of datatype in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have created a table with column `id` as `varchar2(20)`. Now I want to modify it and change size to 13 i.e column `id varchar2(13)`. How to achieve it? Thanks in  advance

p.s.: I don`t have any data in my table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: if you don't have any data, you may easily drop the table and create it again with corrected types. Otherwise you may try the command "alter"

Comment: sorry i have not mention DBMS..i am using oracle 10g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this for Oracle:-

```
alter table tablename modify 
( 
   column_name    varchar2(13)
);
```

Also If you dont have any data in the table then you can also `drop` the table and then `create` the table with the columname as `varchar2(13)`

Comment: why would you recommend dropping the table and recreating? They'd have to recreate any triggers and grants as well. Your `ALTER` statement is more than sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

Just run this query for MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE column `id` varchar2(13);
```

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) for more details. If you have additional constraints on this column, specify those as well.

Comment: OP has mentioned now that it is Oracle 10g!